# Hidden div is moving when it's shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

+++++i add mention+++++

thanks guys for your answers,
but, i think, i missed something to write more.

when i click the button to show the div(#pop), it works right at the scroll on the top.

but, when i go down the scroll, the div(#pop) goes up in the window(height:0) not in "bottom:10%" like at the scroll on the top.

so, i'm trying your answers now, but, i'm not succeed yet T_T HELP!! :)

=================================================================================

Here are my codes.

I have a floating menu and one button of them works for showing a div `id = pop`, which is floating too.

I want to hide the div `#pop` when window starts, and when the button's clicked, it shows.

So I added codes `display:none` to hide, but when i click the button to show the div `#pop`, the div `#pop` is anywhere, not in `bottom: 10%` in CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#scrolltop"><img src="btnUp.png"></a><br/>
        <img src="btnMe.png" id="pop_bt"><br/>
    <a href="#scrollbottom">
        <img src="btnDown.png">
    </a>    
</div>

<div id="pop">
    <div>
        POP UP
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pop{
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    color: #fff; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom :10%;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxtop = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        $('.menu').stop();
        $('.menu').animate({"top": document.documentElement.scrollTop + boxtop}, 800); 
    });  
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pop_bt').click(function() {
        $('#pop').show();
    });
    $('#pop').click(function() {
        $('#pop').hide();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxtop = $('#pop').offset().top;
    alert(boxtop);
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        $('#pop').stop();
        $('#pop').animate({"top": document.documentElement.scrollTop + boxtop}, 800); 
    });  
});
```

Actually, I'm not a programmer, just a designer, so I'm very fool of HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: so the button is visible but not at the bottom? also, check our markup, you have a closing <a> a tag in div.menu

Comment: very fool of html/css/javascript and not a programmer but coding jquery hard code, what you are!

Comment: luvson i guess it would be the best to create a jsfiddle

Comment: Would you mind setting up a fiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle of LUVSON issue :- http://jsfiddle.net/E8vXx/

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z9uaM/2/) to recreate the complete problem

Comment: The fiddle of @ArunPJohny seems working.

Comment: many thanks guys, but your fiddles don't work T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display none is removing your button from the layout.
Same on .hide().
Use opacity 0 to hide the dig but keep it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a fiddle, I can do some guess work only. Looks like the line below is the problem:

`$('#pop').animate({"top": document.documentElement.scrollTop + boxtop}, 800);`

It sets a `top` value and moves the layer to some other place. It should work fine if you remove that.

Comment: but actually, when i don't write "display:none" in CSS, it works very well. Just, i write "display:none", it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use this...

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $("#pop").hide();
    $("#button_id").click(function()
    {
      $("#pop").show();
    });
    });
```

is this you actually need?

Comment: are you remove dispaly:none from your css? you should.